# chi2 + z-test not yielding the same results?

Tags: contingency-tables, z-test

With a 2x2 contingency table, I believe a chi2 test should be equivalent to a z-test -- from Wikipedia: "Two-by-two contingency tables: When the test is applied to a contingency table containing two rows and two columns, the test is equivalent to a Z-test of proportions."

However, when I actually test this in Python, I get different p-values:

```
from scipy.stats import chi2_contingency
from statsmodels.stats.weightstats import ztest
import random
n_points = 10
x1 = [random.random() < .61 for i in range(n_points)]
x2 = [random.random() < .65 for i in range(n_points)]

print 'ztest', ztest(x1, x2)
contingency_table = np.array([[sum(x1), len(x1) - sum(x1)], [sum(x2), len(x2) - sum(x2)]])
chi2, p, dof, expected = chi2_contingency(contingency_table, correction=False)
print 'chi2 result', p
```

Output:

`ztest (-1.0954451150103326, 0.2733216782922979)
chi2 result 0.2635524772829724`

Why is this?

Comment: How is that much of a difference?

Comment: Both methods rely on approximations. Not familiar with Python/scripy versions of these two tests. In R, one of them uses a 'continuity correction' by default, which can occasionally lead to noticeably different results. Particularly if you're interested in a one-sided effect, you might consider 'Fisher's Exact Test'. // If you are willing to share the four frequencies involved, maybe someone on this site can discuss this more precisely. As it stands, I view this as a Python debugging question, rather than a statistics question.

Comment: @MichaelChernick it's a large enough difference that it's not attributable to numerical precision, so I was wondering why it occurred in two supposedly identical tests.

Comment: @BruceET, here's an example output from the above script: 

    x1 = [False, True, False, False, True, True, False, True, False, False]
    x2 = [False, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, True]
    ztest (-0.42857142857142844, 0.6682351417952495)
    chi2 result 0.653095114932182

Comment: My initial guess is one of the two would be using the continuity correction, and the other would not. Does Python not document its functions?

Comment: @Glen_b this is a good thought but not the problem, no, I checked.

Comment: It may be of interest to note that the square of the Z-statistic is *exactly* $6/5$ and the chi-squared p-value (which has one degree of freedom) corresponds to a chi-squared statistic of *exactly* $5/4.$ These observations rule out speculations about inexact calculations, for instance, and hint at what the code is doing.  (I cannot find online documentation for `ztest`.)

Answer (score 2):

I think the main issue here is that many computer programs to not seek
exact P-values above about 0.15 because failure to reject is the clear decision.
Also note that in the traditional chi-squared contingency table procedure,
the expected count is $E_{21}=4.5 < 5$ for the cell with observed count
$X_{21} = 4;$ this automatically triggers a warning message.

Here are some outputs of relevant procedures from R and Minitab 17.

```
TBL = matrix(c(6,4,5,5), byrow=T, nrow=2); TBL
TBL
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    6    4
[2,]    5    5

chisq.test(TBL)   # Contingency table test for indpendence or homogeneity

        Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction

data:  TBL
X-squared = 0, df = 1, p-value = 1

Warning message:
In chisq.test(TBL) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect

chisq.test(TBL, corr=F)  # Turning off continuity correction

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  TBL
X-squared = 0.20202, df = 1, p-value = 0.6531

Warning message:
In chisq.test(TBL, corr = F) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

---

```
prop.test(TBL)  # test for equality of two proportions

        2-sample test for equality of proportions with continuity correction

data:  TBL
X-squared = 9.9604e-33, df = 1, p-value = 1
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
  -0.4338565  0.6338565
sample estimates:
prop 1 prop 2 
   0.6    0.5 

Warning message:
In prop.test(TBL) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect

prop.test(TBL, corr=F)

        2-sample test for equality of proportions without continuity correction

data:  TBL
X-squared = 0.20202, df = 1, p-value = 0.6531
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.3338565  0.5338565
sample estimates:
prop 1 prop 2 
   0.6    0.5 

Warning message:
In prop.test(TBL, corr = F) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

---

```
fisher.test(TBL)  # Fisher Exact Test for 2x2 table, uses hypergeometric dist'n

        Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  TBL
p-value = 1
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
  0.1865694 12.3957696
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
  1.469665
```

---

Minitab:

```
Test and CI for Two Proportions  # Z = (.4 - .5)/SE aprx Std Normal

Sample  X   N  Sample p
1       4  10  0.400000
2       5  10  0.500000


Difference = p (1) - p (2)
Estimate for difference:  -0.1
95% CI for difference:  (-0.533857, 0.333857)
Test for difference = 0 (vs ≠ 0):  Z = -0.45  P-Value = 0.651


* NOTE * The normal approximation may be inaccurate for small samples.

Fisher’s exact test: P-Value = 1.000
```

Comment: Thanks! But I don't think either hypothesis explains the problem.

"many computer programs to not seek exact P-values above about 0.15" ~ the formulas here are relatively straightforward and should be easy to approximate pretty closely, and the gap is quite large (>.01 in many cases). Also, I don't think the results agree even if the p-values are low. 

"Also note that in the traditional chi-squared contingency table procedure, the expected count is E21=4.5<5..." ~ the discrepancy persists at high counts as well.

Comment: Perhaps you can get a better view of this using a dataset with a substantial amount of data and a clearly significant effect. // If you think your software or your code has a bug, this is not the forum for that discussion. // Taking your software (and your use of it) out of the picture, I believe comments by Michael Chernick and Glen_b, and my examples have addressed the statistical issues.

Comment: I observe the discrepancy in both Python and R, which suggests to me that it's not just a peculiarity of a particular statistical package.

Comment: As I mentioned, software does not always strive to give exact P-values above the range used for deciding significance. You get P-value about 0.65. That the value in a couple of the printouts I showed. 'Continuity corrections', known to be conservative, give larger (non-rejection) P-values. Perhaps someone else can explain the issues in a way that is more helpful to you.

Comment: @statistician409 R is consistent between a two-sample z-test for proportions and a chi-squared test for the two-by-two case as long as you are consistent about continuity corrections. If you're getting a difference in R, I am pretty sure your problem is you're either not using one of them correctly or you have an issue with the continuity correction.

Comment: I agree that prop.test and chisq.test are consistent in R, but I think that's because one literally calls the other. My comment that R was inconsistent was based on the fact that fitting a logistic regression model (eg using glm) seems to run some kind of z-test if you call summary but doesn't yield the same p-values as chisq.test. But it occurs to me now that that might be a different z-test which is perhaps incomparable.